# Default Website, Sharepoint Apps and SSL conflict

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2007

I have an internal facing webserver with various apps running inside the default website on port 443 (SSL).

I wanted to install MOSS 2007 on the same server and rum a portal/collaboration app using the same port 443. I was under the impression that if you use host headers, you can do that. It turns out it is not the case. Sharepoint installation automatically stops the default web site.

I've been searching for a solution for a while and I can't believe this is not a common issue. Is there a solution to this?

Thanks,
EJM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to use host headers to run multiple SSL sites on IIS under normal circumstances. To run multiple SSL sites on the same server, you would need to give them separate IP addresses.

It looks like [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true) might also be a solution, but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using command line configuration, see

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html